# "hoverClass" property of droppable() working only first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am doing a drag and drop POC which as follows

http://jsbin.com/aqocok/9/edit#preview

There are two tables side by side. In that span elements are present.
I can drag `<span>` **(ss)** elements from **left side table** into **right side table** (vice versa) and that should be appended to `<td>` of **right side table.**

While dragging and dropping onto particular `<td>` of **Table 2** that `<td>` will be highlighted because of jquery UI `droppable()` function's option `hoverClass`.

Problem here is, that is working only once. When I drag back and try to drop again onto same `<td>`, it is not getting highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you applied the css style to the span element when the `ss` is dragged back. So the culprit is the following line:

```
$(ui.helper).parent().css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
```

Change it to the following line should work:

```
$(ui.helper).parent().removeAttr('style');
```

But I would suggest you to minimise changes to the style attribute, it can easily lead to this kind of bug which is difficult to track down. Try to use add/remove classes instead.

Comment: Hey...Thank you..!! that worked like a charm!!!...also cleared concept of difference between adding/removing class and adding/removing styles.

Comment: Here is updated link [http://jsbin.com/aqocok/11/edit#preview](http://jsbin.com/aqocok/11/edit#preview)

Comment: I learned it the hard way as well. Good to know the answer was helpful! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not especially familiar with jquery-ui, but it looks like this code:

```
//disable dragging of current td
$(this).droppable("option", "disabled", true);
```

is disabling the droppable blocks after something is dropped into them. Would removing that code get you what you want?